# Почему при добавлении элемента в list(), он разбивается на части?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = list(map(str, input().split()))
b = list() 

b += a[0]
b += a[1]

print(b)
```

Ввод: `asd` `asd`
Вывод: `['a', 's', 'd', 'a', 's', 'd']`

Comment: Ввод: asd asd
Вывод: ['a', 's', 'd', 'a', 's', 'd']

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `+` переопределён для списков и он ожидает список в качестве второго аргумента. Строка в Python может быть представлена как список отдельных символов.

Подозреваю, что проверив тип второго аргумента и обнаружив, что это не список, метод `list.__add__()` пытается привести аргумент к типу `list`, примерно так:

```
def __add__(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, list):
        value = list(value)
    ...
```

Поэтому надо делать либо так:

```
b.append(a[0])
```

либо:

```
b += [a[0]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А почему нужно обязательно скобками делить так?

Comment: @RONEGA, потому что `+=` это метод `extend`, а не `append`. `extend` принимает список и добавляет его элементы себе

Comment: @gil9red, отличное пояснение, спасибо!